# How to say "I want to enjoy" in a correct way?

Tags: глаголы

How to say "I want to enjoy" in a correct way? Is it correct to say "Я хочу насладиться"? I saw [the table](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F) and I've confused. Which form should I choose from that table for "to + verb"?

[image]

Comment: "Я хочу насладиться" is absolutely correct

Comment: You can't say so without addition of an explicit dependent object (насладиться - чем именно?). "Хочу получить удовольствие" on its own is OK since it expresses a desired good feeling from anything, be it mentioned before or not.

Answer (score 6):

The verb **хотеть** requires either a subordinate clause or an infinitive.

> Я хочу, чтобы ты мне помог. 
>   Я хочу петь, танцевать, **наслаждаться** жизнью. 
>   Иду на концерт, хочу **насладиться** творчеством этого музыканта.

Наслаждаться is an imperfective verb in the form of the infinitive, насладиться is a perfective verb..

Comment: Russian has just one form of the infitive, it's better to paraphrase the last sentence, something like: "Наслаждаться is the infinitive of an imperfective verb, насладиться is the infinitive of a perfective verb."

Answer (score 6):

It depends on the context:

> 1. If you want to enjoy intangible things like weather, vacation, spring (the season), then a better form is: "***Я хочу радоваться*** солнцу / отпуску / весне..."
> 2. If you want to enjoy an object, such as, a book, a song, a video game, a movie. When you watch a movie in the evening, or read a book over a weekend. You may use: "***Я хочу насладиться*** книгой / фильмом / музыкой..."
> 3. If you want to enjoy something over and over again. For example, you want to enjoy music every day of your life, or you want to tell your loved one that you want to enjoy every day of your future life together. Then you may use: "***Я хочу наслаждаться*** музыкой." Or "***Я хочу наслаждаться*** каждым днём моей жизни с тобой."
> 4. If you want enjoyment for the sake of enjoyment, then you may say: "***Я хочу наслаждений.***"

In the first three cases one uses an infinitive verb form after "хочу".

Answer (score 1):

"I want to enjoy" is something, that you want to do in the future, so you should use the word from the first column (future - будущее).
"Я хочу насладиться" is correct, but rarely used and sounds cheesy. The common saying is: "Я хочу получить удовольствие".